# What does “buco del culo” mean here?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, meaning

I was reading some politicians’ quotes and this one from Vittorio Sgarbi, immediately caught my attention

> Vergogna! Altro che valori! Valori del buco del culo, questa è la storia! Ci sarà forse una querela per questo? Non credo. Il buco del culo ha dei grandi valori.

What does he mean with “buco del culo”? I know what it is but does it have another meaning? Like when you say c***o instead of “oh mannaggia!”. But I don’t know, it doesn’t make sense to me. What would “il buco del culo ha dei grandi valori” mean? If it’s literal it sounds weird...
Anyway, what does it mean in this context and how do  I use it?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 3):

To better understand the context of the citation we could refer to an [article](https://www.lettera43.it/it/articoli/cronaca/2016/03/01/lossessione-di-sgarbi-per-il-lato-b/163850/amp/) talking about Vittorio Sgarbi’s lexical obsession for the B-side:

> Nel 1998 non era andata meglio a Italia dei Valori. «Vergogna!»,
>   attaccò il Nostro. «Altro che valori! Valori del buco del culo, questa
>   è la storia! Ci sarà forse una querela per questo? Non credo. Il buco
>   del culo ha dei grandi valori. Perché no? Si può negare? Sicuramente
>   ci sarà una querela: si dirà 'Ecco Sgarbi...'. Ma perché la parola
>   'valori' è di qualcuno? La parola 'Italia' è di qualcuno? O sono
>   sequestrati per sempre da parte di uno che ha stabilito, senza sapere
>   niente di letteratura, di arte, di civiltà, di grammatica... niente, e
>   pensando di comandare l'Italia!? Ma andate... no, niente da fare».

He was referring to the Italian political party [Italia dei Valori](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italia_dei_Valori), which happened to be in the Italian Parliament in those days, and which was founded by a former public prosecutor active during the early ‘90s.

He was considered a symbol of some kind of reinassance of politic in Italy, bringing with him a concept of integrity.

In this quote “valori del buco del culo” is an epithet and some kind of wordplay just to say that these values (valori) were not so high and precious.